# Найти числа в строке и заменить их

Tags: java, строки

Нужно найти все числа в тексте и заменить число на буквенное представление числа из словаря Map, не могу придумать алгоритм , где в цикле прочтения строки ,сходу находились числа и заменялись на слова из мапы.

Comment: Ешь слона частями.

Comment: `Pattern.compile("\\d").matcher(string).replaceAll(matchResult -> map.get(Integer.parseInt(matchResult.group())));`